# Content fit to window

Tags: html, css, object, hyperlink, window

can you help me with that, the object after I added navbar isn´t fit to window.I think that is becouse I added navbar, and css is wrong. I tried editing code like html and css, but it isn´t working.I want to navbar be ahead and body was at full page and animation on background working. Thank´s for answer!

```
    <nav class="navbar">
  <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</span>
  <a href=/index.html><img src="https://i.ibb.co/VtLx8my/f19ada7376b147df815f4dc7438317e0-5.png" alt="Webstránka MENU" class=logo width="210" height="100">
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu"></a>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-links active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-links">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-links">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-links">Archived</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <section class="main">
    
<div class="context">
        <h1>Web MENU</h1>
      <h3>Welcome!</h3>
    </div>


<div class="area" >
            <ul class="circles">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
            </ul>
    </div > 
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700');
    
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    body{
        font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .context {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top:50vh;
        
    }
    
    .context h1{
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    
    .context p{
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: px;
    }
    
    .context h3{
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    
    .area{
        background: #4e54c8;  
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);  
        width: 100%;
        height:100vh;
        
       
    }
    
    .circles{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .circles li{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
        bottom: -150px;
        
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(1){
        left: 25%;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    
    .circles li:nth-child(2){
        left: 10%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        animation-delay: 2s;
        animation-duration: 12s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(3){
        left: 70%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        animation-delay: 4s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(4){
        left: 40%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        animation-delay: 0s;
        animation-duration: 18s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(5){
        left: 65%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(6){
        left: 75%;
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        animation-delay: 3s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(7){
        left: 35%;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        animation-delay: 7s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(8){
        left: 50%;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation-delay: 15s;
        animation-duration: 45s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(9){
        left: 20%;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        animation-delay: 2s;
        animation-duration: 35s;
    }
    
    .circles li:nth-child(10){
        left: 85%;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        animation-delay: 0s;
        animation-duration: 11s;
    }
    
    
    
    @keyframes animate {
    
        0%{
            transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
            opacity: 1;
            border-radius: 0;
        }
    
        100%{
            transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
            opacity: 0;
            border-radius: 50%;
           }
       
    }
       
    
         /*General CSS*/
    :root {
      --blue: #007bff;
      --indigo: #6610f2;
      --purple: #6f42c1;
      --pink: #e83e8c;
      --red: #dc3545;
      --orange: #fd7e14;
      --yellow: #ffc107;
      --green: #28a745;
      --teal: #20c997;
      --cyan: #17a2b8;
      --white: #fff;
      --gray: #6c757d;
      --gray-dark: #343a40;
      --primary: #007bff;
      --secondary: #6c757d;
      --success: #28a745;
      --info: #17a2b8;
      --warning: #ffc107;
      --danger: #dc3545;
      --light: #f8f9fa;
      --dark: #343a40;
      --breakpoint-xs: 0;
      --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
      --breakpoint-md: 768px;
      --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
      --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
      --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI",
        Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif,
        "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
      --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas,
        "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
      box-sizing: border-box !important;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 450;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: #212529;
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .navbar {
      font-size: 18px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, blue 0%, lightblue 100%);
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      z-index:1000;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    
    .main-nav {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .main-nav li{
      
    }
    .nav-links{
      padding: 14px 16px;
      display:block;
    }
    .nav-links,
    .logo {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
    .nav-links:hover,
    .nav-links:focus
    .nav-links .active,
    .logo:hover,
    .logo:focus{
      background: darkblue;
    }
    
    .main-nav li {
      text-align: left;
      justify-self:flex-end;
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
    
    .logo {
      padding: 15px 16px 14px;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      align-self:flex-end !important;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      font-size: 24px;
      margin-right: 5%;
      float: right;
      padding: 1.5px 16px;
    }
    .main-nav {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: none;
    }
    .active {
      display: block;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar .main-nav{
        display: flex;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
      }
      .main-nav li{
        justify-self:flex-end;
        align-self: flex-end;
      }
    
      .nav-links {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    
      .logo {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px 16px;
      }
    
      .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
      }
    
      .logo:hover,
      .nav-links:hover {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      }
    }
    .container:nth-of-type(1) {
      padding-top: 60px !important;
    }
    .container {
      min-width: 100%;
      display: block;
      padding: 1%;
      margin: 0px auto 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .table {
      table-layout: auto;
      padding: 0.5%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      min-width: 100%;
    }
    .table td,
    .table th {
      border: solid #ededed;
      padding: 0.5% 1%;
    }
    th {
      text-align: center;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
      background: #eeeeee;
    }
    .main h1{
      background: url('http://www.gregswebdesignkc.com/AICGP/assets/images/bldg1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center/100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4%;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0px -1%;
    }
    
    .section-1 h1{
      background: url('http://www.gregswebdesignkc.com/AICGP/assets/images/bldg1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center/100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4%;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0px -1%;
    }
    .panel{
      margin-bottom: 1.5%
    }
    .panel p{
      padding:2% 1%;
      text-align:center;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      margin-top: 1%;
      border-radius: 14px;
      border: #777 solid 4px;
    }
    
    .lead{
      font-size: x-large
    }
    
    section{
      margin-top:.5%;
      margin-bottom: .5%;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6{
        margin: 10px 0 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-weight: 800;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    section{
        padding-bottom:5%;
    }
    
    .row{
        position:relative;
    }
    
    .row:first-child{
        position: relative;
        margin-top:80px !important;
    }
    hr{
      margin: 2% 35%;
      color:#ededed;
    }
    .section-split{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 2%;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
      font-size: 17.5px;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      border: 3px solid #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
      -mox-box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
      -ms-box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
      box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
      padding: 1% 2%;
      border-left: none;
      margin-left: 1%;
      margin-right: 1%;
    }
    
    
    /* BS4 CSS that seems not to work */
    
    .float-xs-left {
        float: left!important
    }
    
    .float-xs-right {
        float: right!important
    }
    
    .float-xs-none {
        float: none!important
    }
    
    @media (min-width:576px) {
        .float-sm-left {
            float: left!important
        }
        .float-sm-right {
            float: right!important
        }
        .float-sm-none {
            float: none!important
        }
    }
    
    @media (min-width:768px) {
        .section-split{
          width: 45% !important;
        }
        .float-md-left {
            float: left!important
        }
        .float-md-right {
            float: right!important
        }
        .float-md-none {
            float: none!important
        }
    }
    
    @media (min-width:992px) {
        .float-lg-left {
            float: left!important
        }
        .float-lg-right {
            float: right!important
        }
        .float-lg-none {
            float: none!important
        }
    }
    
    @media (min-width:1200px) {
        .float-xl-left {
            float: left!important
        }
        .float-xl-right {
            float: right!important
        }
        .float-xl-none {
            float: none!important
        }
    }
    
    @-ms-viewport {
      width: device-width;
    }<style>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? At the moment your code works in that the animation shows and the window (initially) has a blue background - albeit with slight margins. However, if you scroll you get a non-blue background. Do you want the whole thing to fit in the viewport or the whole thing to be scrollable and the background blue (and the animations working from the bottom of the page not the bottom of the viewport) or...

Comment: Yes, that's how I imagine it

Comment: Which one? a) everything in the viewport or b) the page scrollable and with blue background?

Comment: b) is that what i imagine it

Answer (score 0):

The blueish background does not extend the full length of the content because the ul.circles has position absolute and therefore does not affect the total height of its parents which have the background color.

If you add the linear-gradient to the unordered list then it will extend the color to full height.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}

.context {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  z-index: 999;
  /* ADDED */
}

.context h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.context p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: px;
}

.context h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.area {
  background: #4e54c8;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);
  /* ADDED */
}

.circles li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
  bottom: -150px;
}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 75%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 85%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 11s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}


/*General CSS*/

 :root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #fd7e14;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #28a745;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #17a2b8;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #6c757d;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;
  --primary: #007bff;
  --secondary: #6c757d;
  --success: #28a745;
  --info: #17a2b8;
  --warning: #ffc107;
  --danger: #dc3545;
  --light: #f8f9fa;
  --dark: #343a40;
  --breakpoint-xs: 0;
  --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
  --breakpoint-md: 768px;
  --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
  --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
  --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 450;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, blue 0%, lightblue 100%);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-nav li {}

.nav-links {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.nav-links:hover,
.nav-links:focus .nav-links .active,
.logo:hover,
.logo:focus {
  background: darkblue;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: left;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  padding: 15px 16px 14px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  align-self: flex-end !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: right;
  padding: 1.5px 16px;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    justify-self: flex-end;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 16px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo:hover,
  .nav-links:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
}

.container:nth-of-type(1) {
  padding-top: 60px !important;
}

.container {
  min-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0px auto 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.table {
  table-layout: auto;
  padding: 0.5%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.table td,
.table th {
  border: solid #ededed;
  padding: 0.5% 1%;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.main h1 {
  background: url('http://www.gregswebdesignkc.com/AICGP/assets/images/bldg1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center/100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px -1%;
}

.section-1 h1 {
  background: url('http://www.gregswebdesignkc.com/AICGP/assets/images/bldg1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center/100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px -1%;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 1.5%
}

.panel p {
  padding: 2% 1%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin-top: 1%;
  border-radius: 14px;
  border: #777 solid 4px;
}

.lead {
  font-size: x-large
}

section {
  margin-top: .5%;
  margin-bottom: .5%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 10px 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.row:first-child {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 80px !important;
}

hr {
  margin: 2% 35%;
  color: #ededed;
}

.section-split {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  font-size: 17.5px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
  -mox-box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px #873939, 8px 8px 8px 2px #888;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  border-left: none;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}


/* BS4 CSS that seems not to work */

.float-xs-left {
  float: left!important
}

.float-xs-right {
  float: right!important
}

.float-xs-none {
  float: none!important
}

@media (min-width:576px) {
  .float-sm-left {
    float: left!important
  }
  .float-sm-right {
    float: right!important
  }
  .float-sm-none {
    float: none!important
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .section-split {
    width: 45% !important;
  }
  .float-md-left {
    float: left!important
  }
  .float-md-right {
    float: right!important
  }
  .float-md-none {
    float: none!important
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .float-lg-left {
    float: left!important
  }
  .float-lg-right {
    float: right!important
  }
  .float-lg-none {
    float: none!important
  }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .float-xl-left {
    float: left!important
  }
  .float-xl-right {
    float: right!important
  }
  .float-xl-none {
    float: none!important
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</span>
  <a href=/index.html><img src="https://i.ibb.co/VtLx8my/f19ada7376b147df815f4dc7438317e0-5.png" alt="Webstránka MENU" class=logo width="210" height="100">
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
  </a>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links active">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">News</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-links">Archived</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <section class="main">

    <div class="context">
      <h1>Web MENU</h1>
      <h3>Welcome!</h3>
    </div>


    <div class="area">
      <ul class="circles">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The content also needs to be brought forward to show above this new background setting.

Comment: Thanks, but nav isn´t responsible

Comment: Ah, I didn't look into nav - I thought the question was about the coloring of the full length.

Comment: Yes, that was ,but I now figured out that is for me important.

Comment: I can understand that but is that a new question or integral to the color background one?